# Retrieving the newsfeed/posts from my Close Friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the newsfeed or posts from my list 'Close Friends'. In Facebook's Graph API Explorer, I tried //xxxxxxxxx/posts where xxxxxxxxx is the id of my 'Close Friends' list and the data shown is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FQL, for example:

> SELECT post_id, message, actor_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM
>   stream_filter WHERE uid = me() and name='Close Friends')

And please remember it's not so stable because of stream table behavior,  Only one feed returned example:
[image]

So, we need to get the uid to make it stable, you should using this query instead:

> SELECT post_id, message, actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id IN
>   (SELECT uid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM
>   friendlist WHERE owner = me() and type='close_friends'))

[image]

And of course you need pagination via created_time. Also , use a high number of LIMIT parameter(example LIMIT 150) would return more stable for both case.

Cheers

Comment: I hadn't thought of using FQL.. I'll go with this one. Thanks for your thoroughly response! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using /profile id/feed, that should work

Comment: Think you will have to go via fql.. not possible via graph for now - [read here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292867337476364/)